# Armory synchronization takes forever. How can I speed it up or retrieve my coins?

Tags: private-key, synchronization, armory

I have an Armory wallet that has been offline for a long time. When I start up that computer it runs just fine, however it is taking forever to download the blockchain. Based on my estimate of the blockchain size 116 gigs, and how much space is on my computer, I estimate it will take another 12 days to finish. I can however run Armory in offline mode and view my private keys.

What is the best way to spend my bitcoins. I would like to set up a new wallet that does not require me to download the blockchain and import the bitcoin addresses from Armory, but I can't find information on how.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the private keys and import them in a lite wallet like Electrum.

You need to run Armory as expert, go to the Wallet's properties dialog and click on the backup center on the right side column